# toggle the title of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML button and it shows another div instead of another div.

All I need is to toggle the text for the button:

```
<input id="blueButton" type="button" value="+ Add a new Team" onclick="
 $('#blueButton').prop('value', 'Hide'); 
 $('#teams').toggle('slow');
 $('#add_block').toggle('slow');">
```

I need to change the button text again from hide to the orgianl title which is `+ Add a new Team`

so the button title is `+ Add a new Team`
if clicked the button title change to `hide` if I click the button again it will change to `+ Add a new Team` again.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#blueButton').val(function(_, value) {
    return value === 'hide' ? '+ Add a new Team' : 'hide' 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#blueButton").toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).val("hide");
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).val("+ Add a new Team");
    }
);
```

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jf7UU/)

Comment: Please note that `toggle` mouse event is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#blueButton').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "+ Add a new Team") { 
        $(this).val("Hide")
    } else { 
        $(this).val("+ Add a new Team")
    }
});
```

EDIT: undefined said the same thing as me, but better, use his :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#teams').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    //Change button Text here
    $('#blueButton').prop('value', 'show');
  });
```

This may not be the exact code you require but it can give you a hint that you can have a callback function which can be used to do things after toggle has finished,

Answer (score 0):

Here is [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/Fwkrg/)

jQ

```
$("#blueButton").live("click", function() {
    $(this).val() == "+ Add a new Team" ? $(this).val("hide") : $(this).val("+ Add a new Team");
});​
```